# Reading multiple CSV files and asynchronously update SQLite

Tags: c#, csv, asynchronous, async-await, sqlite

My console app needs to read several big CSV files to update its data, which are stored in a SQLite database. I am new to C# and would like to know if there are ways to improve this sample code I wrote to simulate the app flow.

What the code does:

The `DataRequester` asks a `DataLoader` object for data. For simplicity, here there is just one `DataLoader` object.

The `DataLoader` check if fileExists. If not, it triggers an event. The event handler is in the `DataRequester` object. If yes, it loads it asyncrously, parse it then triggers an event. The handler is in the `DataRequester` object and will store the data in the database.

My doubts are about:

- The way I implemented the async await pattern
- The way I used `Task.Delay().Wait()`
- If I should expect better performance using a `ParallelFor` instead than the simple `for` loop but the bottleneck would be the disk
- Should I limit the created threads?

**Note:** The following code has been checked in Visual Studio Code with .Net Core 1.1.1

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;

namespace tasks
{

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("** Program Starts");
            WriteLine("** Update Data");

            var requester = new DataRequester();
            requester.UpdateData();

            WriteLine("** Program Ends");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class DataEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public string FileName {get; set;}
        public List<string> Data {get; set;}
        public DataEventArgs(string fileName, List<string> data)
        {
            FileName = fileName;
            Data = data;
        }
    }

    public class DataRequester
    {
        int numberOfCSVFiles = 1000;
        int completed = 0;

        public void UpdateData()
        {

            // The real code loads fileNames from a CSV File
            var fileNames = new string[numberOfCSVFiles];
            var loader = new DataLoader(fileNames);
            loader.OnDataLoaded += HandleDataLoaded;
            loader.OnDataNotFound += HandleDataNotFound;
            loader.RequestData();
        }

        public void HandleDataLoaded(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
        {
            completed++;
            float percentage = ((float) completed/ (float) numberOfCSVFiles)*100;
            WriteLine($"Received the data for file: {args.FileName}. Request Completion: {percentage.ToString("n2")}%");

            // Update SQLite Database ...
        }

        public void HandleDataNotFound(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
        {
            completed++;
            float percentage = ((float) completed/ (float) numberOfCSVFiles)*100;
            WriteLine($"Data not found for file: {args.FileName}. Request Completion: {percentage.ToString("n2")}%");
        }
    }

    public class DataLoader
    {
        private static readonly Random random = new Random(); 

        public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs> OnDataLoaded;
        public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs> OnDataNotFound;

        public string[] FileNames {get; set;}
        public DataLoader(string[] fileNames){FileNames = fileNames;}

        private bool CheckFileName(string fileName)
        {
            var fileExists = (random.Next(10)<9)?true:false;
            return fileExists;
        }

        private DataEventArgs LoadData(string fileName)
        {
            // Simulate data loading
            int waiting;
            lock(random)
            {
                waiting = random.Next(10)*1000;
            }
            Task.Delay(waiting).Wait();
            return  new DataEventArgs(fileName, new List<string>());
        }

        private Task<DataEventArgs> LoadDataAsync(string fileName)
        {
            return Task.Run<DataEventArgs>(() =>
            { 
                return LoadData(fileName);
            });
        }

        public async void RequestData()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for(int i=0; i<FileNames.Length; i++)
            {
                var fileName = String.Concat("file #",(i+1).ToString());
                if(CheckFileName(fileName))
                {
                    var task = LoadDataAsync(fileName).ContinueWith((t) => 
                    {
                        OnDataLoaded?.Invoke(this, t.Result);
                    });

                    tasks.Add(task);
                }
                else
                {
                    var args = new DataEventArgs(fileName, new List<string>());
                    OnDataNotFound?.Invoke(this, args);
                }
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            WriteLine("Request completed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One simple thing of note: don't create a new random number generator in an instance method. You're bound to get dupes that way. make it a static member of the class: `private static readonly Random random = new Random();` and feel free to `lock` on it around its usages if you're worried about concurrency.

Comment: Good point, I was wondering why I had a lot of dupes! +1! I updated my code.

Comment: `private static int` inside the `UpdateData` method? This is not a valid C# code and thus unfortunatelly off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted the two lines in the wrong place when I edited my code. I fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Event mistakes

You're not using events correctly.

> ```
> public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs
> {
>   public string FileName { get; set; }
>   public List<string> Data { get; set; }
>   public DataEventArgs(string fileName, List<string> data)
>   {
>       FileName = fileName;
>       Data = data;
>   }
> }
> ```

The properties should be read-only.

---

> ```
> public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs> OnDataLoaded;
> public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs> OnDataNotFound;
> ```

Events do not have the `On` prefix. You use it only for methods that raise a particular event like:

```
private void OnDataLoaded(..) => DataLoaded(this, ..);
```

---

> ```
> private DataEventArgs LoadData(string fileName)
> ```

or

> ```
> private Task<DataEventArgs> LoadDataAsync(string fileName)
> ```

We do not return `EventArgs` from methods (unless it's a factory method). You should return the actual result or fire the event there.

---

> ```
> public void HandleDataLoaded(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
> ```

and

> ```
> public void HandleDataNotFound(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
> ```

These event handlers should not be `public` and their names are by convention wrong. It should be e.g.

```
public void loader_DataNotFound(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
```

---

> ```
> public void loader_DataNotFound(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
> ```

Also by convention the `EventArgs` parameter is usually named just `e`. `args` is the parameter you get from `Main`.

## async mistakes

You're not using `async` correctly and you did it exactly the wrong way around.

> ```
> private Task<DataEventArgs> LoadDataAsync(string fileName)
> ```

This method should be *decorated* with `async` but it isn't whereas

> ```
> public async void RequestData()
> ```

this one should not. `async` needs to be used with a return type. If it's `void` then you should use just `Task`. You may/should use `void` only for `async` event handlers.

---

## Naming mistakes

The classes and method names are not optimal e.g. the `DataLoader` has a method called `RequestData` and the `DataRequester` a method called `UpdateData`.

If I saw them for the first time I expect the `DataLoader` to have a `LoadData` method and the `DataRequester` a `RequestData` method. If it's updating something then it should be an `Updater` or otherwise it's really very confusing.